# Opt out of getting notifications about binding edits to some or all community wiki answers

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications, community-wiki

I recently posted [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/218076/102999). It is a community wiki looking to identify 378 characters. In less than 48 hours, [it has been edited 55 times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/218076/56). That translates to over 50 notifications sent to me about teensy edits to one big thing that I don't have much investment in.

[Another similar answer I posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/205117/102999) was [edited 278 times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/205117/279) in less than two months!

**Can we have the ability to not get notifications from edits to community wiki answers, other than ones that require review to be published?**