# Does notification in comment work for gold tag badge holders if they are not the only person that reopened/closed a question?

Tags: support, notifications, dupehammer

The answer for the question [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/339911) states the following:

> For questions: The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question, provided they were the only one to do so. Users who have closed or reopened a question without a binding close vote (i.e. without a gold tag badge or a moderator vote), and those who bindingly voted, but other users were also involved (e.g. closed by User1, User2, and Moderator) cannot be notified.

It's not quite clear for me, does a gold tag badge holder get notified from a comment via `@` if for instance they are second person who voted to close/reopen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question, provided they were the **only one** to do so.

(emphasis mine)

I just scienced it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332751/295232), and I didn't get a ping from a comment posted by my sockpuppet.

Comment: I've asked because of [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361706/how-to-find-posts-with-tags-in-the-body#comment1206846_361706) addressed to you :)

Comment: LOL! I reopened that because ColleenV seems to have found another solution. But perhaps it's better if she posts it under the duplicate question.

Comment: There was a [bug report earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345569/comment-notifications-for-close-voters-regression-from-2018?noredirect=1&lq=1) that this type of comment *did* result in a notification when it wasn't supposed to. Might want to answer that saying that it's fixed.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog That bug appears to be specifically for moderators, not gold tag badge holders in general. And as far as I'm aware, that bug still exists.